# Many mobile apps clients on the same server

Tags: cordova, meteor

I am building an app for multiple clients and I need to specify for what client a mobile build is made for. I'm trying to put a file defining a variable ( reactiveVar ), for exemple:

```
appIdVar = new ReactiveVar('8s7df8s7dy8f7s87323');
```

for this, I trying to take the value from the settings.json but it will not work, settings.json is deployed on the server side.

I think put it on the mobile-config.js, but how to retrieve this value on the app ?

Comment: How do you make the connection between mobile clients and server? AJAX Requests?

Comment: No, all mobile clients is a Meteor App and the Server too. I just need to make differents mobile products with a variable whose will take different data from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Settings stored under the `public` key are available on the client under [`Meteor.settings.public`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-settings).

Comment: Ok, if I try that what happens when I build a mobile app with appId on Meteor.settings.public with one value, and anothe build with another value. I will put both apps on the Play Store and each one will works with the diffente appId value ?

Comment: I'm not sure if that would work reliably because the settings will be updated on the clients if they are changed on the server: *Changes to Meteor.settings.public at runtime will be picked up by new client connections.* (from [Meteor.settings](https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-settings))